# How to compute this integral : $\oint \bar{z}^n dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How to compute this integral : $$\oint_{|z|=a} \; \bar{z}\;^n dz$$

I choose $z = ae^{i \theta}$, and so $\bar{z}\;^n = a^n e^{-i\theta}$

And $$\oint_{|z|=a} \; \bar{z}\;^n dz = a^{n+1}i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\theta(1-n)} d\theta = \left. \dfrac{ a^{n+1} e^{i\theta(1-n)}}{1-n} \right|_0^{2 \pi} $$

In the correction there is : $$\oint_{|z|=a} \; \bar{z}\;^n dz =
\left| \begin{array}{cl} 2\pi ia^2 & \text{if} \;n=1 \\
0 & \text{if} \;n \neq 1\end{array}  \right. $$

But it seems to me that the $\frac{1}{1-n}$ factor forbids $n=1$

What is my error ?

Comment: In your third line, in the RHS of the first equality, consider the case $n=1$ seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case $n=1$ should be considered seperately.

$$\oint_{|z|=a} \; \bar{z}\;^n dz = a^{n+1}i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\theta(1-n)} d\theta = \left. \dfrac{ a^{n+1} e^{i\theta(1-n)}}{1-n} \right|_0^{2 \pi}$$

only if $n \neq 1$. If $n=1$, you have:

$$a^{n+1}i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\theta(1-n)} d\theta= a^2i (2 \pi)$$